# C++ template operator overloading with different types, auto return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make an overload with `auto` return type (C++11)

I already read [C++ template operator overloading with different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153450/c-template-operator-overloading-with-different-types), but that's not exactly that I'm trying to do.

I have a class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Attr
{
    public:
    Attr(const T& v) : value(v) {};

    typedef T type;
    T value;
}
```

Now i try to add some operator (`=`,`+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,`%`) with `auto` return type, so I add inside `Attr` this code:

```
template<typename U> T& operator=(const U& v){value=v;return value;};  //work

template<typename U>
auto operator+(const U& v) -> std::decltype(Attr<T>::type+v) const //line 29
{
  return value+v;
}; //fail
```

I try to replace `std::decltype(Attr<T>::type+v)` with:

- `std::decltype(value+v)`
- `std::decltype(Attr<T>::value+v)`
- `std::decltype(T()+v)`

And I also try to remove `const`, but no change, I always have these errors:

```
ORM/Attr.hpp:29:47: erreur: expected type-specifier
ORM/Attr.hpp:29:47: erreur: expected initializer
```

---

EDIT:
First, `decltype` is not a member of `std`.

It should be:

```
template<typename U> auto operator+(const U& v)const -> decltype(value+v) {return value-v;};
```

Final code:

```
template<typename T>
class Attr
{
    public:
    Attr(const T& v) : value(v) {};

    typedef T type;
    T value;

    template<typename U> auto operator+(const U& v)const -> decltype(value+v) {return value-v;};
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `std::decltype(Attr<T>::type+v)` with `decltype(value+v)`.

Comment: @gx_: that won't work I'm afraid, because you can't access member variable outside of a member function body. You need to use `std::declval`

Comment: Yes, it compile whene i remove std::. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyProwl I'm admittedly not yet an expert in the C++11 standard, but are you sure about that? It appears that the function definitions are meant to reside in the class definition, shouldn't `value` be visible?

Comment: @jerry: Right, I shall correct myself: only names of members declared *before* the use of `this` outside the body of a member function are visible. I placed the operators before the declaration of `value`, which is why I was getting a compiler error. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: @AndyProwl Ah, I see. It's a fair point, though, there's no reason the data members *have* to come first. In fact, in the common paradigm where `public` members are listed first, followed by `protected`, and then `private`, that won't be the case (if `value` were `private`, as it probably should be). Good to keep in mind.

Comment: @AndyProwl Thank you for the correction and explanation! (and +1 to your edited answer below)

Comment: @gx_: Thank you (and jerry) for actually proving me wrong and force me to look into the Standard. Lesson learnt for me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First problem**

There is no such a thing as `std::decltype`. `decltype` is a keyword. Secondly, inside the `decltype` expression you are trying to add an object and a type. Although I understand what you meant to do, for the compiler, that is non-sense.

You could use `std::declval<>` for that purpose:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator+(const U& v) ->
    decltype(std::declval<T>()+v) const //line 29
{
    return value+v;
};
```

Or, if you have declared your `value` data member *before* the point where you are referring to it outside the body of a member function, you could do:

```
template<typename U>
auto operator+(const U& v) ->
    decltype(value + v) const
//           ^^^^^
//           Valid only if the "value" data member has been declared before
{
    return value+v;
};
```

**Second problem**

Usually, `operator +` is defined as a (possibly friend) free function, not as a member function, so that you could actually make it work even when the object of your type is not being passed as the first operand.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But apparently, declval is not needed to make it work, just remove std::.

Comment: @Krozark: Uhm, that's very strange. `decltype(value+v)` should not compile in that context. Perhaps this is a non-standard extension of your compiler

Comment: I use gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) , with "g++ -g -std=c++0x -o ... -c ..."

Comment: @Krozark: Yep, sorry, I made a mistake - shame on my, I suck, etc. ;) The restriction is that members accessed through the `this` pointer outside the body of a member function must have been declared before. When trying to reproduce the problem, I placed the member operators *before* the declaration of `value`, and therefore I was getting a compiler error. You most likely have your operators defined *after* the declaration of `value`.

Comment: " You most likely have your operators defined after the declaration of value" Yes it is.

Comment: @Krozark: OK, that clarifies then. I edited the answer, thank you for your patience