# Overloading Assignment operator in template based class

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, operator-overloading, template-meta-programming

I am writing a library to support a type of integers which have two template parameters `INT_BITS` and `FRAC_BITS`. I was successful in writing a convert function to convert different class types from one to another [ which vary in values of `INT_BITS` and `FRAC_BITS` ]. But when I try to use it in the overloading of assignment operator it doesn't work. Please suggest me a way to implement it. I have gone through links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014294/operator-overloading-on-class-templates) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854371/c-template-operator-overload) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153450/c-template-operator-overloading-with-different-types) , but none of the solution seems to be working.

The Class definition :

```
template<int INT_BITS, int FRAC_BITS>
struct fp_int
{
public:
    static const int BIT_LENGTH = INT_BITS + FRAC_BITS; 
    static const int FRAC_BITS_LENGTH = FRAC_BITS;

private:
    ValueType stored_val;
};
```

The convert function definition :

```
template <int INT_BITS_NEW, int FRAC_BITS_NEW>
fp_int<INT_BITS_NEW, FRAC_BITS_NEW> convert() const
{
    typedef typename fp_int<INT_BITS_NEW, FRAC_BITS_NEW>::ValueType TargetValueType;

    return fp_int<INT_BITS_NEW, FRAC_BITS_NEW>::createRaw(
        CONVERT_FIXED_POINT<
            ValueType,
            TargetValueType,
            (FRAC_BITS_NEW - FRAC_BITS),
            (FRAC_BITS_NEW > FRAC_BITS)
            >:: exec(stored_val));
}
```

The operator definition goes as :

```
template <int INT_BITS_NEW, int FRAC_BITS_NEW>
fp_int<INT_BITS_NEW, FRAC_BITS_NEW>
    operator =(fp_int<INT_BITS,FRAC_BITS> value) const
{
     fp_int<INT_BITS_NEW,FRAC_BITS_NEW> a = value.convert<INT_BITS_NEW,FRAC_BITS_NEW>();
     return a;
}
```

When I try this it works :

```
fp_int<8,8> a = 12.4;
fp_int<4,4> b = a.convert<4,4>();
```

But when I attempt this it shows type conversion error:

```
fp_int<8,8> a = 12.4;
fp_int<4,4> b;
b = a;
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Assignment-operators should typically take their argument *by reference*. Also, you're not *assigning* in your assignment operator, that is, you don't modify the left operand. That's surprising: it doesn't follow the behaviour of the built-in assignment.

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @m.s. Please find the file at [repo_link](https://github.com/coder-mike/FixedPoint/blob/master/fixed_point.hpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you're working with normal classes, not templates. You have a class `SomeType` and you want to have an assignment operator for this class so you can assign objects of type `OtherType` to objects of this class. So something like this:

```
SomeType obj1;
OtherType obj2;
obj1 = obj;
```

For this to work you would write the assignment operator for `SomeType` like this:

```
SomeType& operator=(const OtherType& other)
{
    // implementation...

    return *this;
}
```

Converting this to templates, `SomeType` and `OtherType` are instantiations of the same template class but with different template parameters.
In this case `SomeType` becomes `fp_int<INT_BITS, FRAC_BITS>` and `OtherType` becomes something like `fp_int<DIFFERENT_INT_BITS, DIFFERENT_FRAC_BITS>`.

So your operator should look like this:

```
template <int DIFFERENT_INT_BITS, int DIFFERENT_FRAC_BITS>
fp_int<INT_BITS, FRAC_BITS>&
    operator =(fp_int<DIFFERENT_INT_BITS, DIFFERENT_FRAC_BITS> value)
{
    // proper implementation for an assignment operator
}
```

Compare the template parameters above to the ones in your example to see the difference. Basically you were trying to do the conversion in the wrong direction, this is why you were getting a compile error regarding type conversion.

Comment: - Thanks a lot , I finally came up with a implementation and understood my mistake.